# i want to remove imageicon according to clicking on button

Tags: java, swing, imageicon

I want to set the icon on a label when button pressed once if pressed twice it will remove i have used `label.setIcon(null);` but it is not working fine for me.

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    if (!"submit".equals(e.getActionCommand()))
    {
       JButton button = (JButton) e.getSource();
       int X = button.getLocation().x;  
       int Y = button.getLocation().y;
       JLabel tick=new JLabel();add(tick);
       tick.setBounds(X+400,Y+15,50,50);           

       if(arr.contains(e.getActionCommand()))
       {            
           tick.setIcon(null);
           arr.remove(e.getActionCommand());
       }          
       else
       {            
           image=new ImageIcon(imageList[0]);
           tick.setIcon(image);
           arr.add(e.getActionCommand());
       }
```

Comment: You need call the invalidate() method in order to make Swing redraw your UI without the icon in the label.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't recreate JLabel and don't add it on each click

```
   JLabel tick=new JLabel();
   add(tick);
```

Create class' field instead and create the label once. If it's initialized just `tick.setIcon(null)`.

Comment: i have done that but whenever i click on another button it get removed

Comment: Then you need more than one JLabel field. You should define as many fields as many buttons you have. Or define a Map<String, JLabel> and store the labels in the map where key could be button's text.

Comment: can you please explain me about Map<String, JLabel>  i didnt get that .

Comment: Instead of tick field define Map<String, JLabel> labels=new HashMap<>(); on click check whether label exists in the map (use clicked button's title as the key). If there is no label in the map create it, add to layout and put in the map. If label exists just set icon to null

Comment: if (map.get(buttonKey)!=null) {map.get(buttonKey).setIcon(null);}

Comment: i get it but cant use because i m adding button dynamically suggest  other ways

Comment: It doesn't matter how you add buttons. All of them have title and you need corresponding jLabels